# How to differentiate between two specific click before form submission in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two events, first one is for **adding new element** and second one is for **editing the elements**.

Without submitting the form, I'm not sure how can I differentiate between them. I need the previous events so that I can use them on submit event. As, there are some conditions which are same for the **add** and **edit**, so I didn't keep them on separate file. But for some conditions, I've to specify if those work for "add" event or "edit" event which I can't seem to find any way.

This is my code :

```
$('.addButton').on('click',function(){
   //console.log('add event');
   $('#forTest').modal('toggle');
});  //after trigerring this will go to the below submit code

$('#submitForm').on('click',function () {
   // some conditions 
   /* where condition is same except the error message are different like for
      add : this message : values are empty
      edit: this message : same values are there
   */

  $('#test_form').submit();
});  


$('.edit-button'.on('click', function(){
  $('#forTest').modal('toggle');  //edit button which will trigger to upper submit form
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what the issue is. It may help to see the associated HTML.

Comment: most likely you have a row id in the data, if its set its edit else its create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable, eg. `action` and set different values in different click listeners:

```
let action;

$('.addButton').on('click',function(){
   action = "add";
   $('#forTest').modal('toggle');
});  

$('.edit-button'.on('click', function(){
    action = "edit";
    $('#forTest').modal('toggle');  //edit button which will trigger to upper submit form
});

$('#submitForm').on('click',function () {

  if(action === "edit"){ /* Edit code */}
  else{ /* Add code */ }

  $('#test_form').submit();
});
```